# Inserting sum of items of list while iterating through it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, logic, sequence

I've been trying to generate a sequence like this

```
1 2 1
1 3 2 3 1
1 4 3 5 2 5 3 4 1
```

The sequence basically inserts the sum of 2 consecutive list elements between them.
Here's my solution:

```
a =[1,1]
h=[]
for j in range(1,5):
    h=a
    for i in range(0,len(h),2):
        h.insert(i+1, a[i]+a[i+1])
    print(a)
    a=h
```

But it's somehow generating half right sequence after 3rd iteration.

```
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1]
[1, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 5, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1]
[1, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 5, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1]
```

Can anyone help with what I did wrong.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List's are handles. If you change one the other changes as well. Here is my suggestion.

```
a =[1,1]
h=[]
for j in range(1,5):
    h=a.copy()
    for i in range(0,len(a)-1,1):
        h.insert(2*i+1, a[i]+a[i+1])
    print(a)
    a=h.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

`h` is redundant. Backward loop is more efficient

```
a = [1, 1]
for j in range(1, 7):
    for i in range(len(a) - 1, 0, -1):
        a.insert(i, a[i - 1] + a[i])
    print(a)
```

```
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 5, 7, 2, 7, 5, 8, 3, 7, 4, 5, 1]
```